# Alamofire - NSURLCache is not working?

Tags: swift, nsurlcache, alamofire

I set my cache as below

```
var cacheSizeMemory = 20 * 1024 * 1024
var cacheSizeDisk = 100 * 1024 * 1024
var sharedCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: cacheSizeMemory, diskCapacity: cacheSizeDisk, diskPath: "SOME_PATH")
NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(sharedCache)
```

Create request with cache policy

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(baseUrl!)\(path)")!, cachePolicy: .ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: timeout)
```

Make a request and get a response with following `Cache-Control` `private, max-age=60`

Then try to check the cache

```
var cachedResponse = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest(urlRequest)
```

value is nil

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem right now, no solution yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up manually adding `Cache-Control` as `private` in the header of my request and it now works. Don't even need to manually check the cache, Alamofire does it for you

```
let cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy = isReachable() ? .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData : .ReturnCacheDataElseLoad

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(baseUrl!)\(path)")!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: timeout)

request.addValue("private", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")

var alamoRequest = Manager.sharedInstance.request(urlRequest)
```

Comment: Would you mind providing us with a code snippet of this?

Comment: it does not work on iOS 8.x however it works fine on iOS 7.1  Is there any way to make it work on iOS 8.x?

Comment: Any clue how does this work with iOS 9? I have tried this out but no help!

Comment: does not work for me either. Server set its cache headers for 10 mins but even I use ReturnCacheDataElseLoad policy, after 10 mins cannot call images from cache

Answer (score 19):

I was able to manually cache pages by writing them to the sharedURLCache like this:

```
    Alamofire.request(req)
        .response {(request, res, data, error) in
            let cachedURLResponse = NSCachedURLResponse(response: res!, data: (data as NSData), userInfo: nil, storagePolicy: .Allowed)
            NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().storeCachedResponse(cachedURLResponse, forRequest: request)
        }
```

NSURLCache seems to **respect the headers sent by the server**, even if you configure the opposite everywhere else in your code.

The Wikipedia API, for example, sends

```
Cache-control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0
```

Which translates to: Must revalidate after 0 seconds.
So NSURLCache says: “OK, I won’t cache anything.”

But by manually saving the response to the cache, it works. At least on iOS 8.2.

Almost lost my mind on this one. :)

Comment: Nice solution. With this one, are we sure that the NSURLCache always returns the cached response, unregarded the headers?

Answer (score 4):

I found that URLCache does not save responses bigger than 5% (1/20) of capacity.

Default cache has memoryCapacity = 512000, it does not save to memory responses greater than 25600.

As a solution extend capacity

Comment: Thanks this led to finding the following:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondatadelegate/1411612-urlsession?language=objc
The response size is small enough to reasonably fit within the cache. (For example, if you provide a disk cache, the response must be no larger than about 5% of the disk cache size.)

Answer (score 2):

[Swift solution for resolving expiration of NSURLcache]

I think that main problem here is this: `ReturnCacheDataElseLoad`.

@arayax gave you the answer that will fix that probably, but my solution would be something like this:

Since I'm using Alamofire for Network requests I've set my configuration:

```
  configuration.requestCachePolicy = .ReturnCacheDataElseLoad
```

And when I make request I do check internet connectivity, if it is true, then clear NSURLCache, so it will force Alamofire to make request on server and not from cache:

```
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        ConfigService.cache.removeAllCachedResponses()
    }

    ConfigService.manager?.request(.GET, ...
```

I hope this will help, maybe for other type of problems with NSURLCache :)

Answer (score 1):

For me it was **Pragma →no-cache** after removing this everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got the cache to work with Alamofire 4 and swift 3 (Semi full function for reference):

```
 func getTheList(courseId : String )->  Void{
        appConstants.sharedInstance.startLoading()
        let TheURL = DEFAULT_APP_URL + "api/getMyList?Id="+ID
        let urlString = NSURL(string: TheURL)
        var mutableURLRequest = URLRequest(url: urlString! as URL)
        mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        mutableURLRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad


        Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
            .responseJSON
           {.......
```