# Save JSON data in the cache of device

Tags: ios, json, swift, caching

I want to save JSON data that I get from the URL in the phone cache. For this I did:

```
// Create a shared URL cache
        let memoryCapacity = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
        let diskCapacity = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
        let cache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: "shared_cache")

        // Create a custom configuration
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        var defaultHeaders = Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders
        configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .UseProtocolCachePolicy // this is the default
        configuration.URLCache = cache

        // Create your own manager instance that uses your custom configuration
        let manager = Manager(configuration: configuration)

        // Make your request with your custom manager that is caching your requests by default
        manager.request(.GET, "http://some_site.az/ru/json-view/1",  encoding: .URL)
            .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                var myJ = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

                var dataForPrint = JSON(myJ)

                var infoTitle = dataForPrint["result"][0]["title"]
                var infoBody = dataForPrint["result"][0]["body"]

                self.aboutUs.loadHTMLString(infoBody.stringValue, baseURL: nil)

                // Now parse the data using SwiftyJSON
                // This will come from your custom cache if it is not expired,
                // and from the network if it is expired
        }
```

but it doesn't cache it at all. What I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

I did say, that I did look to this question, modified it and it doesn't work!

Comment: Just saying "It doesn't work" can't help you. Please provide *what you did*: you said you modified the similar question, what did you do?  What are your modifications? Do you have an error message? If it doesn't cache, where does the data go? Follow the data with breakpoints. Until you provide more context with something specific, your question *is* a duplicate and already has answers.

Comment: @ericd Just it doesn't cache my data and each time sends request to server. I do not know how to describe my problem

Comment: I know that you don't know how to describe your problem. That's why I was trying to help you with these hints. :) You should put a breakpoint in your code, say for example on the `let configuration` line. Then run your app and inspect the contents of the `cache` constant that's the line before. Then run it again and compare the contents of `cache` with the previous result. Is it populated properly? If yes, the problem is elsewhere. If no, try to fix this first. Etc.

Comment: @ericd it prints me always `<NSURLCache: 0x78ea0870>`

Comment: Have a look here, it looks like there's solutions for you (or at least, important info) in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785693/alamofire-nsurlcache-is-not-working

Comment: @ericd can you help me with it in the chat? Please! I have work over it since the morning and nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76371/discussion-between-ericd-and-orkhan-alizade).