# Alamofire ImageDownloader ReturnCacheDataElseLoad not respected

Tags: swift, caching, alamofire

I'm not able to force ImageDownloader to use ReturnCacheDataElseLoad properly (to use previously downloaded pictures from cache)

Server which I'm using in my app returns below headers:

```
headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=600";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "image/jpeg";
    Date = "Mon, 29 Feb 2016 13:25:22 GMT";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = Express;
}
```

ImageDownloader is initialized by configuration described below:

```
let configuration = ImageDownloader.defaultURLSessionConfiguration()

// If we do not use image filters, it is advised by Alamofire to set the memory capacity of the NSURLCache to zero to avoid storing the same content in-memory twice.
configuration.URLCache?.memoryCapacity = 0

// Existing cache data should be used to satisfy a URL load request, regardless of its age or expiration date.
// However, if there is no existing data in the cache corresponding to a URL load request, the URL is loaded from the origin source
configuration.requestCachePolicy = .ReturnCacheDataElseLoad
```

The problem is that after 10 minutes (600 sec defined by Server in cache-control header) when I reopen the app in offline mode, all previously  downloaded pictures disappears.

I've tried various solutions from here (like discribed here: [Alamofire - NSURLCache is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785693/alamofire-nsurlcache-is-not-working)) but nothing helped.

EDIT:
Another thing I've just observed (and can impact the behaviour above) is that the folder /Library/Caches/{appname}/fsCachedData is being erased at some point (unknown, by the system?)