# Alamofire 4 Swift Cache Control - HTTP Statuscode 304 (If Modified Since)

Tags: ios, swift, caching, alamofire

When I receive a HTTP Status Code 304 from my server, the server doesn't send any content data, because nothing changed.

Now I want to use the cache control from Alamofire 4 (for Swift 3). But I can't figure out how does it work. I find some examples for Alamofire 3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785693/alamofire-nsurlcache-is-not-working)

```
 Alamofire.request(req)
    .response {(request, res, data, error) in
        let cachedURLResponse = NSCachedURLResponse(response: res!, data: (data as NSData), userInfo: nil, storagePolicy: .Allowed)
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().storeCachedResponse(cachedURLResponse, forRequest: request)
    }
```

So I think the structure will be similar in Alamofire 4. But where is my content saved? I was hoping that I can do something like this

Pseudocode:

```
if response.statusCode == 304 {
   return cacheControl.response
}
```

Does anybody have an idea? 
In doubt I have write it on my own.

Comment: Hi, I have your same problem .. how did you solve it? thank you.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to recover the old cache contents in case the Status code is 304 like this:

```
let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60
    let memoryCapacity = 500 * 1024 * 1024; // 500 MB
    let diskCapacity = 500 * 1024 * 1024; // 500 MB
    let cache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: "shared_cache")
     configuration.urlCache = cache
    return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
}()
```

And

```
func getData(url:URLConvertible,completionHadler:@escaping(Data?,ErrorMessage?)->Void){

    let headers: HTTPHeaders =
    [   "Authorization":token!,
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "if-None-Match":  self.loadEtagUserDefault(keyValue: "Etag")
  ]
  
  
  self.sessionManager.request(url, method: .get, parameters:nil, headers: headers)
  
  .validate()
  
  .responseJSON { (response) in
    
    switch (response.result) {
    case .success:
      
      // SAVE THE RESPONSE INSIDE THE CACHE
      
      self.saveCache(response)
      
      //---
      
      if let unwrappedResponse = response.response {
        _ = unwrappedResponse.statusCode
      }
      // If all went well, I'll return the date
         // Recovery Etag from the Header
      let etag =  response.response?.allHeaderFields["Etag"] as? String
      //update in memoria Etag
      self.saveEtagUserDefault(etagValue: etag!, key: "Etag")
      
      print("stato codice: \(String(describing: response.response?.statusCode))")
      completionHadler(response.data,nil)
      
      break
    case .failure(let error):
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
      let url1:URLRequest? = try! response.request?.asURLRequest()
      
      //Nel caso lo status code è nil perciò il sito non e raggiungibile restituisce la vecchia cache
      guard let _ = statusCode else {
        
        let dataOld = self.loadOldDataCache(url: url1!)
        completionHadler(dataOld,nil)
        
        return
      }
    // If the status code is 304 (no change) I return the old cache
      if statusCode == 304 {
        
        print("beccato codice 304 ***")
        let dataOld = self.loadOldDataCache(url: url1!)
        guard let _ = dataOld else {
          completionHadler(nil,ErrorMessage.error(description: "data nil"))
          return
        }
        completionHadler(dataOld,nil)
        return
      }
      
      
    // *** IN CASE OF ERROR 401 refresh the token and recursively call the same method
      print("error - > \n    \(error.localizedDescription) \n")
      
      print("stato codice2: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
      
    
    }
  
  
}

}


//Save the response in the cache
private func saveCache(_ response: (DataResponse<Any>)) {
  let cachedResponse = CachedURLResponse(response: response.response!, data: response.data!, userInfo: nil, storagePolicy: .allowed)
  let mycache:URLCache = self.sessionManager.session.configuration.urlCache!
  mycache.storeCachedResponse(cachedResponse, for: response.request!)
}


// Given a Request URL returns the old CACHE in case the site is unresponsive or offline
private func loadOldDataCache(url:URLRequest)->Data?{
  let myCache:URLCache = self.sessionManager.session.configuration.urlCache!
  let cacheResponse = myCache.cachedResponse(for: url)
  return cacheResponse?.data
}

// Except in memory Etag
private func saveEtagUserDefault(etagValue:String,key:String)->Void{
  
  UserDefaults.standard.set(etagValue, forKey:key)
  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
  
}
// Recovery from the memory Etag
private func loadEtagUserDefault(keyValue:String)->String{
  return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: keyValue) as? String ?? "0"
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Diego asked me in the comments how I solve this problem. Unfortunately I can't solve it the right way.

What I did is that I created my own NetworkManager for Alamofire.

```
    class NetworkManager {

     static let sharedInstance: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20.0
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20.0
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        configuration.urlCache = nil
        return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
      }()
   }
```

The important line is `configuration.urlCache = nil`. So Alamofire won't cache anything. Surely I know that this is not the right way but atm this is a solution that is o-kay for my use cases.

You call this manager like this

```
    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: contentAuthorization).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            //success
        case .failure(let errorValue):
            print(errorValue)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I have to show the old content (cached) when the status code is 304.
example:
1) start the App I call the API and save the data in the cache
2) If the status code and 304 display the old data in the cache
3) If the status code is different from 304 then I update my cache.
I hope I understand and I apologize for my English.

Comment: I have no time to test it, but it's sounds and looks okay. Thank you.